# the evaluation of the Jones polynomial of an alternating link at $ t= -1 $.

Tags: graph-theory, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I've been looking at some graph polynomials and I found a very nice relation between the famous Tutte polynomial of graphs and the no less famous Jones polynomial of links.

Using this relation I was able to show, that for an alternating link $ L $ with an alternating diagram $D$:

$$
\lvert V_{L} (-1) \rvert 
= \# \{ \text{spanning trees of the Tait graph of } D \}.
$$

(I used the Tutte polynomial of the Tait graph of $D$.)

Then I found in [this paper](http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/~abhijit/papers/qatwist.pdf), the equality: 
$$
\lvert V_{L} (-1) \rvert 
= \det (L)
$$
for $ L $ an alternating link.

So my question is:

For an alternating link $ L $ with an alternating diagram $ D $, how do I prove that 
$$ 
\det (L) = \# \{ \text{spanning trees of the Tait graph of } D \}?
$$

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the equality you have shown is well known, though I don't know where its written down (this is somewhat close but orthogonal to my interests so don't take this opinion too seriously). Actually,  I think the first author of the paper you linked mentioned it in a recent talk I attended.

I am not sure what you want to show if you already believe the equalities you've written down, but in fact $V_L(-1)=\Delta_L(-1)$ is true for any link (where $\Delta_L(t)$ is the Alexander polynomial and the determinant is usually defined as $|\Delta_L(-1)|$).

According to Wolfram.Mathworld, the equality $V_L(-1)=\Delta_L(-1)$ is present in Jones' 1985 paper where he introduced the polynomial, so that might be a good place to start.

For entertainment purposes: there is an "interesting" interpretation to the relationship you proved by a quite famous mathematician outside of knot theory http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/Opinion1.html

Answer (score 1):

In *A spanning tree expansion of the Jones polynomial*, Morwen Thistlethwaite (journal link [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938387900036), pdf link [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/thistlewaitejones.pdf)) proves that if $G$ is the Tait graph of an alternating diagram $D$ of a link $L$, then the Tutte polynomial of $G$ evaluated at $x=-t$ and $y=-t^{-1}$ is the Jones polynomial of $L$ (up to multiplication by $\pm t^k$ for some $k$). Your result relating $|V_L(-1)|$ to the number of spanning trees in the Tait graph $G$ is obtained by letting $t=1$ in Thistlethwaite's result.

It is worth noting that in this paper Thistlethwaite uses the relationship between the Tutte polynomial and the Jones polynomial to prove some of Tait's conjectures on the properties of alternating links.